# Как посчитать количество слов в введенном тексте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, текст

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import fileinput
import subprocess

sa = None


def _open():
    global sa
    sa = askopenfilename()
    print(sa)
    f = open(sa, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    content = f.read()
    txt.delete(1.0, END)
    txt.insert(END, content)


def _save():
    global sa
    global content
    content = txt.get(1.0, END)
    f = open(sa, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()


def _about():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')
    win.geometry('300x200')
    lab = Label(win, text="First string version 1.4\n"
                          "Developer:NewModernSoft\n"
                          "2019.02.16\n"
                          "Copyrighted by NewModernSoft©")
    lab.pack()


def _exit():
    global sa
    if askyesno("Exit", "Saved changes?"):
        if sa is None:
            sa = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("text file", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
        _save()
    root.destroy()


def _newwindow():
    subprocess.call('First_String.exe')


root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

root.geometry("1000x800")

root.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')

root.title("First String")



txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame = Frame(root, height=30)
l1 = Label(frame, text="Word count:")
l2 = Label(frame, )
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
l1.pack(side=LEFT)
l2.pack(side=LEFT)

txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="New", command=_newwindow)
fm.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
fm.add_command(label="Save", command=_save)

hm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=hm)
hm.add_command(label="About Program", command=_about)
hm.add_command(label="Exit", command=_exit)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _exit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А приведённый вами код имеет отношение к вопросу?

Comment: проще всего, пожалуй так: len(text.split()) ну или же text.replace('.',' 
 ').replace('!',' ').replace('?',' ').replace(';',' ').lower() # replace все знаки препинания

Comment: Да,код снизу имеет отношение к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно регуляркой сделать разбиение символом, но чтобы в результат не попали знаки пунктуации и т.п. придется сделать дополнительную обработку или использовать другую регулярку -- для поиска определенной последовательности символов (например `findall(r'\b[\S]+\b', txt)`):

```
from re import split

txt = """First string version 1.4
         Developer:NewModernSoft
         2019.02.16
         Copyrighted by NewModernSoft©
      """

# filter уберет пустые элементы
words = list(filter(None, split(r'\s+', txt)))
print(words)
# ['First', 'string', 'version', '1.4', 'Developer:NewModernSoft',
#  '2019.02.16', 'Copyrighted', 'by', "NewModernSoft©"]

print(len(words))  # 9
```

**PS.**

Для этой задачи лучше всего использовать специализированные библиотеки, например [nltk](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit), но если что-то простое обрабатывается, то и регулярок хватит.

Comment: Извините,но мне надо посчитать слова введенные пользователем.В l2 должно выводится количество слов                                                                                                                                 txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame = Frame(root, height=30)
l1 = Label(frame, text="Word count:")
l2 = Label(frame, )
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
l1.pack(side=LEFT)
l2.pack(side=LEFT)

txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')

Comment: @BouncyShow, а вы абстрагируйте от кода и просто используйте `txt = input()`. Если бы у вас, к примеру, файл был, то тут тоже самое -- способ получения строки не имеет значения, только алгоритм

Comment: Я привел код,который отвечает за ввод текста

Comment: @BouncyShow, забыл что у вас там tk используется... Вытаскивайте из виджета tx текст и парсите регуляркой. Если я не ошибаюсь, то это через `txt.get(1.0, END)`. С учетом того что я выше писал будет так: `text = txt.get(1.0, END)` + `words = list(filter(None, split(r'\s+', text)))` + `...`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @BouncyShow, если помогло, то поставьте галочку у ответа :)

Comment: Хорошо,поставлю

Comment: argument of type 'int' is not iterable вот в этой строчке:l2 = Label(frame, s)

Comment: @BouncyShow, стопудов вы количество слов (тип `int`, целочисленное) передали в `Label` который ожидает `str` (строка). Попробуйте так `str(len(words))`

Answer (score 0):

Можно через regexp, например так:

```
from re import findall

txt = """First string version 1.4
         Developer:NewModernSoft
         2019.02.16
         Copyrighted by NewModernSoft©'
      """

wcount = len(findall(r'[^\s\d\W]+', txt))
```

Результат: *wcount = 8*

Comment: Извините,но мне надо посчитать слова введенные пользователем.В l2 должно выводится количество слов txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) frame = Frame(root, height=30) l1 = Label(frame, text="Word count:") l2 = Label(frame, ) frame.pack(side=BOTTOM) l1.pack(side=LEFT) l2.pack(side=LEFT) txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH) scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview) scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')

Comment: Я привёл пример кода для подсчёта количества слов. :о) А исходный текст можно брать откуда угодно, в том числе и из поля ввода txt.

Answer (score 0):

Если считать словами просто группы символов, разделенные пробельными символами:

```
text = '   aweferg      waeferg waege d wqeweg       '
print(len(text.split()))  # 5
```